# JDK version when exporting and creating war in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, java

My question is the following:

if you have a Java 1.6 compiler set in [window->preferences->java->compiler]

When you do [right click on project -> export as -> war]

or

[right click on project -> export as -> jar]

is it compiled with the Java 1.6 compiler? or with the one JAVA_HOME is pointing at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The export operation (JAR or WAR, or anything) has nothing to do with the build process.

When you export, the workbench first ensures that all relevant projects are built. It does it by simply firing an Eclipse event to have a build done. Your projects will be built with whatever they were configured to be built with, using the compiler settings that they were configured to be compiled with. The compiler that is being used for the purpose is not necessarily the one that you have `JAVA_HOME` pointed at; it is the one that is defined in the workbench's preferences.

Once the build is done, the export handler performs the actual export of files from your workbench (which now includes the `.class` files for each built project) into an archive (JAR, WAR and so forth).

Comment: I would like to add that although the workspace may have a default compiler, some projects have by default a different jdk, so it's not necessarily the one associated with the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

It sets it with setting mentioned in Preferences. In your case the one you mentioned and not `Java_Home`

Comment: and that is true for both war and jar, right? Because the odd thing is that I'm getting a weird unsupported major.minor class version exception while deploying to AWS, and AWS uses a 1.6 jdk

Comment: I had a similar issue some time back with Spring. And till now I couldn't solve it. For some reason, it just doesn't work with java 7

Answer (score 0):

Unzip your war and jar and check your manifest file, for the build-jdk line.